# Brace expansion and compound command

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

I do not understand why these two loops are different.  It must have something to do with when the brace expansion is performed and how white space is interpreted

```
for i in b{e,\ }s ; do echo $i ; done

for i in bes b s ; do echo $i ; done
```

and consider this too

```
for i in $(echo b{e,\ }s) ; do echo $i ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `for i in b{e,\ }s ; do echo $i ; done`, the brace expansion `b{e,\ }s` is expanded into two arguments, one is `bes` and another is `b s` so the `for` loop has two values to iterate over. Note that here `b s` is a single argument.

On the other hand, in `for i in bes b s ; do echo $i ; done`, you are explicitly mentioning three arguments to iterate over (separated by spaces), namely `bes`, `b` and `s`.

In the third case, the command substitution `$(echo b{e,\ }s)` will generate three arguments `bes`, `b` and `s` so again the `for` loop have three values to iterate over just like the second case.